# Javascript OOP callback "this" apply

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

i have a problem when creating `callback` on my own `EACH` function.

i'm using OOP way to accompolished it.

basically, i create my own javascript library that mimicry `JQUERY` habits.

check this fiddle out on action : https://jsfiddle.net/6pk068ep/1/

```
<div class="parent">
    <p class="child">child</p>
</div>
<div class="parent">
    <p class="child">child</p>
</div>
```

The JavaScript:

```
"use strict";

(function(window) {

    var i, $, $Obj, ele; // global variable

    $ = function(el, length) {
        return new $Obj(el, length); // create new object
    };

    $Obj = function(el, length) {

      ele = document.querySelectorAll(el); // get selector element 

        this.length = ele.length; // count the length of ele

        for (i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
            this[i] = ele[i]; // loop it
        }

    };

    $Obj.prototype = { // object prototype

       each : function(fn) { // create method each just like jquery

       var arr = []; // create array to store value

       for (i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {          
         arr.push(this[i]); // push it to arr variable
         }

       fn.apply(this, arr); // IS THIS THE CORRECT WAY TO APPLY IT? 
       return this; // return this, so, it's chainable for other method

      }

    };

window.$ = $; // make dollar sign global object

})(window);

$(".child").each(function() {

    console.log(this);
    this.style.color = "red"; // not working, what's wrong with my code? is it because my "apply" wrong?

});
```

how to get those `.child` style color to red?

what's wrong with my code?

thanks in advance...

Comment: `var i, ele; // global variable` will surely be a source of errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you say `each()` it is assumed that the callback will be called for each item in the collection, so in this case you need to call the callback in the for loop.

Also note that variables like `ele` and `i` are not global, they are suppose to be local to the function where you are using them.

```js
"use strict";

(function(window) {

  var $, $Obj; // global variable

  $ = function(el, length) {
    return new $Obj(el, length); // create new object
  };

  $Obj = function(el, length) {
    var ele, i;

    ele = document.querySelectorAll(el); // get selector element 

    this.length = ele.length; // count the length of ele

    for (i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
      this[i] = ele[i]; // loop it
    }

  };

  $Obj.prototype = { // object prototype

    each: function(fn) { // create method each just like jquery
      var i;

      for (i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        fn.call(this[i], this[i], i);
      }

      return this; // return this, so, it's chainable for other method

    }

  };

  window.$ = $; // make dollar sign global object

})(window);

$(".child").each(function() {

  console.log(this);
  this.style.color = "red"; // not working, what's wrong with my code? is it because my "apply" wrong?

});
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <p class="child">child</p>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <p class="child">child</p>
</div>
```

Comment: fabolous! thank you so much Mr. Arun P Johny! just one thing, you make var i to local variable. so, i must redefined it over, over, and over again. what's the problem if i defined it first on top of Object?

Comment: @ChingChing https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ygfqez48/1/ - is suppose to print 0-14 4 times like in https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ygfqez48/2/

Comment: ahh! GOTCHA! i understand it now! thank you so much Mr. Arun P Johny!